# How to drop db2 source connection and reopen it after the lookup is done in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, db2, informix, sql-server-data-tools

I am getting a connection `timeout` error on one of the `package` that I am running into.

```
Error:  " SQL1224N  The database manager is not able to accept new requests, has terminated all requests in progress, or has terminated the specified request because of an error or a forced interrupt"
```

I have talked to my DB2 administrator and he was asking me to close and reopen the connection as it will automatically close after 15 mins idle time.

Please find the attached image we are working on and please help me to work on this.

[image]

**Issue**: The package will throw an error after 1 hour(1GB data) saying the data manager cannot accept any more requests and throws an error on source connection.

I haven't found any solution so far on how to resolve this. Any help is appreciated on how to resolve this.

Source: DB2

Lookup: Informix

Destination: SQL

Comment: SQL1224N is tricky to diagnose. The message description itself says "There are many reasons for which this message can be returned". https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01224n.html
See the "User response" in the message description, and ask your DBA to raise a support call (PMR) with IBM if further help is required.

Comment: If you have a reproducible SQL1224N, then the Db2 DBA should be able to add more value than asking to reconnect. There's not enough detail in your question to give you any specific answer. If the Db2 server is repeatedly throwing SQL1224N then reconnecting from SSIS wil not resolve the issue, and the Db2 DBA should know that. Ask the Db2 DBA for more diagnostics, what queries or situations cause the SQL1224N to repeat etc. Opening a PMR with IBM (if you have paid support) will force your Db2-DBA to provide diagnostics.

Comment: Can you replace your Lookup with a Merge Join of two source components?